# How are multi vs single engine helicopters categorized?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter

When looking at the FAA category, class, type list, you have airplane single-engine land, multi-engine land, etc. but just rotorcraft helicopter, gyrocopter, etc.

How do I specify a multi vs single engine helicopter? Does the FAA differentiate, or are you able to fly a multi engine helicopter the day you get your helicopter certificate?

For context, I'm making a web form where an operator can add their aircraft, and I want to be able to sort by single or multi engine helicopters because sometimes people request a multi engine helicopter.

I ended up just doing this:
[image]

Comment: A lot of helicopters require [a type rating to fly](http://registry.faa.gov/TypeRatings/). I'm not sure what you mean by "specify in my own way", specify to who?

Comment: Good point. I clarified the question

Comment: Do you really mean helicopters with multiple engines, or are you actually asking about helicopter with multiple rotors?

Comment: Helicopters with one vs two engines.

Comment: It seems you question boils down to "what information is available from FAA site to determine if a given rotorcraft is a multi-turbine helicopter?"

Comment: I know you've asked for US, but you could do it easy in Australia which uses two simple classes for non-type rated helicopters - Multi-engine helicopter (MEH) and Single-engine helicopter (SEH).

Comment: Can you make your own mapping table so when operators add their aircrafts they have to specify whether it is single engine or multi engine? Unless you have master table of aircraft somewhere....

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. I've also considered just auto filling in the information from the FAA database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the FAA, rotorcraft powered by more than one powerplant are not separately classified.

A [random N-number](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=N102H) search for a random twin-engine helicopter—[AgustaWestland AW109](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgustaWestland_AW109#Specifications_.28AW109_Power_with_PW206C.29_2850_Kilo_version)—using the FAA registry yielded the type as: Rotorcraft.

However for a Boeing 707, the type came back as: Fixed Wing Multi-Engine.

I couldn't find a place where the different classes are listed on the FAA website, whether for fixed-wing or rotorcraft.

Comment: ymb1 is correct. There is no "multi-engine" rating for helicopters such as there is for fixed wing. With my rotorcraft *category* helicopter *class* certificate, I can fly any helicopter regardless of the number of engines so long as I do not exceed the requirement for a type-rating ( ie - if the helicopter is more than 12,500 lbs).